# Kotlin array initialization throws null pointer exception

Tags: kotlin

I'm a total beginner with kotlin, and I'm trying to initialize an array using the constructor that accepts a size and a function. This is what I have:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var ary = Array(5, {x -> x + 2})
    println(ary[2])
}
```

But it's throwing a null pointer exception on the first line. Why is this happening?

---

EDIT: I'm the original poster's professor, and we're trying to get this working together. Here's some more info:

I've edit the code above to be the full program. The version of Kotlin we have installed on our server is:

```
$ kotlinc -version
info: kotlinc-jvm 1.2.70 (JRE 1.8.0_144-jdk_2017_08_24_20_46-b00)
```

When I try to compile and run from the command line I get:

```
$ kotlinc example.kt -include-runtime -d example.jar
$ java -jar example.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ExampleKt.main(example.kt:2)
```

I'll note that this code compiles just fine for me on my laptop, which has an older version of Kotlin.

Comment: Code works fine as is and prints out `4`.

Comment: The code has no problem. How about uploading the IDE screenshot with NPE.

Comment: If you have an exception it might be worth adding the stacktrace to the question as well. Usually this gives you more information about the why the error happend.

Comment: I added a bunch of info about the version of Kotlin and the exact error we're getting (I'm John H's professor).

Comment: Just out of curiosity change that line to `var ary = Array(5) {x -> x + 2}` and see what happens.

Comment: I tried that, got the exact same error

Comment: Same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53233325/kotlin-2d-array-throws-nullpointerexception-when-using-command-line-compiler-on

Answer (score 5):

This is [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28285) in the AOT-compiled (OS-dependent) version of the Kotlin compiler. Please see the issue for updates.